# Queries on Phonegap plugin development

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-plugins

I was going through couple of documentations on writing an Android plugin using Phonegap. I've some questions on that.

1. What is the purpose of `callbackId` parameter in `execute()` method of the Plugin class

Can you please an explanation for these questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript to Native calls can be synchronous or asynchronous, in case of asynchronous the `callbackId` is used by internal PhoneGap API to call the result function in the Javascript once the native code execution is completed.

`callbackId` will not be processed if the native code has nothing to return back which is equivalent to `PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT`.

For more detail information please refer to [PluginManager](https://github.com/callback/callback-android/blob/master/framework/src/com/phonegap/api/PluginManager.java).exec() method

Comment: So is it basically to identify who called this method?

Comment: not just identify, when native processing is done and JS needs to be called back; `callbackId` is used to call that specific function

Comment: I meant to identify the JS script method that invoked the plugin. Is that correct?

Comment: this is the way phonegap uses it internally - for error callback `PhoneGap.callbackError('"+callbackId+"', " + this.getJSONString()+ ");` and for success callback `"PhoneGap.callbackSuccess('"+callbackId+"',"+this.getJSONString()+");"`

Comment: you can find more detail about `Phonegap.callbacks[]` in this source base js file - [phonegap.js base](https://github.com/callback/callback-android/blob/master/framework/assets/js/phonegap.js.base)